# The blessing of Pru U'rvu

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, pregnancy-birth, creation, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

"The reason why a mule cannot reproduce is because is wasn't blessed by the blessing of Pru U'rvu during the Six Days of Creation. "

Someone showed this to me while I was learning in Israel. I remember that it is not a Gemara. I think it is a Medrash. Where is the source to this?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. I recommend the [tour], which helps to explain how this site is different from some others you may have used.